# Jest cannot find module from window object in a Vue/Vuex project

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, jsdom

I have a config attached to the `window` object in `/public/js/settings.js` file:

```
window.mySettings = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
}
```

I import these settings in a vuex store file `baz.storage.js` in a vue project:

```
import settings from 'mySettings';
```

It all works except that jest doesn't understand this export:

```
Cannot find module 'mySettings' from 'baz.storage.js'
```

And so the whole jest suite fails.

Comment: do you have a module called `mySettings`? how do you include the `/public/js/settings.js` to your script?

Comment: in `index.html` in `public` directory: `<script src="/js/settings.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If `/js/settings.js` is included in your page, you don't need import it in the **baz.storage.js** but make sure `settings.js` is include at first.

**Eg:**

```
<script src="/js/settings.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script3.js"></script>
```

`settings.js` is added at first in the above example so that `window.mySettings` will be available for the `script2.js` and `script3.js`

---

once you declared a variable in the `window` it is declared at the **global scope** and it can be accessed from all the other scripts.

**Eg:**

```
console.log(window.mySettings)
```

Comment: Anyway, if I make it `const settings = window.mySettings` the jest test suite fails, it doesn't see the `settings` variable.

Comment: in which file do you assign `window` setting to a `const`?

Comment: There is no such file